# Download files from s3 to ec2 instance using Azure DevOps (AWS ToolKit)

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, azure-devops, aws-cli

I am trying to download files from s3 to ec2 instance in Azure DevOps by using AWS CLI in Build Pipeline. I am able to get the download logs but the data is not downloaded on my ec2 instance.

Same command works while executing from EC2 instance. It doesn't give me any error from DevOps but I do not see the data moved to my instance.

Thanks for your help.

[image: Log Screenshot]

[image: Command Used]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this but I am getting Invalid Instanceid error. But I checked my instance id is correct. Not sure if there are special permission for ssm operations.

Comment: Hi Monika. You could check if the [SSM Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html) has been installed. Please refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47036168/13464420) for more methods to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you, this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51528442/13464420):

> The AWS CLI calls the AWS API. The APIs for Amazon S3 do not have the ability to interact with the operating system on an Amazon EC2 instance.

So when you run the same command in the EC2 instance, it could work as expected. But it doesn't work in Azure Devops Pipeline.

You could try to use the [aws cli send-command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html) to send the `aws s3 cp command` to the EC2 instance.

Here is an example:

[image]